# URL location(lat,lng) and types in google maps api - android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google places api for android, i can obtain the information. If I specify the types='hospital'for location=-33.8670522,151.1957362 it gives information. Without specifying the types parameter i can obtain the results for other lat, lng values, but it shows 'Zero Results'for other lat,lng if i specify the 'types' parameter in url. Give me some idea.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=13.006389,80.2575&radius=500&sensor=false&types=food&key="Pls add your own key"
```